# Tool to test RDBMS SQL dialect for ANSI SQL standard compliance

Tags: testing, sql-standard, development

We are developing an interface to our internal data storage and manipulation tool that would allow people to use SQL dialect.

We decided that it would be perfect to make our SQL dialect as close to the standard as possible.

Currently I'm trying to find a tool that would test our implementation of query language and make a verdict about its compliance and list missing details.

Have anyone ever encountered anything like this?

Comment: http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm but that does not support modern SQL

Comment: Great, thank you! But I need exactly the opposite. I need a tool that can send queries to my "database" and then show me the list of features that are not implemented according to one of the standard SQL implementations.

Comment: I think you should write your own tests. Then you can run the tests and the results will show which features are working and which not. You can get an idea and start with [Postgres' (regression) tests](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/test/regress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after looking at SQLite unit tests and postgreSQL unit tests we decided to use these tools

- https://github.com/anse1/sqlsmith
- https://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/doc/trunk/about.wiki